# Spark on Mesos how to set location of the driver

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, mesos

I have Spark running on Mesos in a cluster mode.

When I submit the job, the driver runs randomly on any slave nodes. Is there a way I can specify the location of the driver? For e.g. IP of the slave I want to run on..

Can I use spark.driver.host

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In [cluster mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html#cluster-mode), that is, using `--deploy-mode cluster` option in the `./bin/spark-submit` command, the driver is launched on a node in the cluster. You should **not** set `spark.driver.host` and/or `spark.driver.port` as this is programmatically set by `SparkContext`.

Comment: OK. Then I'd appreciate if you mark this answer as correct so that others also benefit from it.